# Installshield - How do I make installshield build the entire cd?

Tags: installshield

Right now the Release build just makes the files necessary for the install. But I want to create the CD structure automatically with InstallShield, so that when I go to Tools, Open Release Folder

it has

```
\Install
\Tools
\Help
autorun.inf
```

I've looked at the execute batch file or copy to folder options for a Release, I was hoping there was something more friendly within InstallShield.

using version 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a feature / component called CDOnly which is not visible, selected, and doesn't copy, but does put the files in the Disk Images / Disk1 folder.

So by changing the default directories of features and putting special things in CDOnly I was able to create the structure I wanted.